# Update array redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I try to update a now playing state in Redux but everytime i call the update and it passes the check it get's added twice to the state.

result is that my filter when mapping (hide the first item) is not working due to the 2 additions.

Sample reducer:

```
import {
    UPDATE_NOW_PLAYING,
    UPDATE_ARTIST_AND_TITLE,
    UPDATE_CURRENT_ARTIST
} from '../actions/actionTypes'
import { nowPlayingUrl, showNumberOfTracks, lastFmApiKey } from '../constants'

const currentState = {
    playHistory: [],
    currentArtist: '',
    currentTitle: '',
    currentShowName: '',
    currentAlbumUrl: 'https://https://url.to.logo/app/app/logo-app.png'
}

const NowPlayingReducer = (state = currentState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_ARTIST_AND_TITLE: {

            if (state.currentArtist !== action.array[0].artist) {
                return {
                ...state,
                playHistory: state.playHistory.concat(action.array[0]),
                currentArtist: action.array[0].artist,
                currentTitle: action.array[0].title,
                currentShowName: action.array[0].showName,
                currentAlbumUrl: action.array[0].albumUrl
            }
        }
        return state

        }

        case UPDATE_NOW_PLAYING: {
            return {
                ...state,
                playHistory: action.payload,
                currentArtist: action.payload[0].artist,
                currentTitle: action.payload[0].title,
                currentShowName: action.payload[0].showName,
                currentAlbumUrl: action.payload[0].albumUrl
            }
        }
        default: return state
    }
}

export default NowPlayingReducer
```

So it works, but the only part is the second addition somehow :(

//Edit:

```
componentWillMount() { 
   this.getNowPlaying()
}

componentDidMount() {
setInterval(async () => {
 await this.updateCurrentInformation()
  }, 10000);
}

updateCurrentInformation = async () => {
try { 
    let currentPlayingResponse = await fetch(nowPlayingUrl + 1 )
    let currentPlayingJson = await currentPlayingResponse.json()
    let newArray = []

      Promise.all(
            currentPlayingJson.nowplaying.map(async (album) => {
                const albumObj = await this.getAlbumInformation(album);
                newArray.push(albumObj);

                this.props.updateArtistAndTitle(newArray)
            })
        );
} catch(error) { console.log(error)};
```

}

togglePlayerType() {

}

```
getNowPlaying = async () => {
    try {
        let nowPlayingResponse = await fetch(nowPlayingUrl + showNumberOfTracks);
        let nowPlayingJson = await nowPlayingResponse.json();
        let newArray = [];

        Promise.all(
            nowPlayingJson.nowplaying.map(async (album) => {
                const albumObj = await this.getAlbumInformation(album);
                newArray.push(albumObj);
                this.props.updateNowPlaying(newArray);
            })
        );

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

getAlbumInformation = async (album) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  let id = JSON.stringify(album.id).replace(/"/g, '');
  let title = JSON.stringify(album.title)
    .replace(/"/g, '')
    .replace(/([&][^&; ]+[;])/g, '');
  let artist = JSON.stringify(album.artist)
    .replace(/"/g, '')
    .replace(/([&][^&; ]+[;])/g, '');

  let dateTime = JSON.stringify(album.datetime).replace(/"/g, '');
  let showName = JSON.stringify(album.showName).replace(/"/g, '');
  let albumUrl = 'https://url.to.logo/app/logo-app.png';

  let obj = { id, title, artist, dateTime, showName, albumUrl };

  try {
    let albumResponse = await fetch(
      `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=${lastFmApiKey}&artist=${artist}&track=${title}`
    );

    let albumJson = await albumResponse.json();
    if (albumJson) {
      url = albumJson.track.album.image[3]['#text'];
      if (url > '') {
        obj.albumUrl = albumJson.track.album.image[3]['#text'];
      } else {
        obj.albumUrl = 'https://url.to.logo/app/logo-app.png';
      }
    }
    resolve(obj);
  } catch (err) {
    resolve(obj);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: You are setting `playHistory` to `action.payload` in the `UPDATE_NOW_PLAYING` case, so it may be that your `action.payload` array already contains the artist twice. I would suggest checking that the `action.payload` is correct

Comment: The update now is only run once in the componentWillMount to initialize the state and fill it. Then it is going well only after the second update (Every 10 seconds) it adds in twice

Comment: Are you confident that the action's payload is being set correctly when you dispatch the action? It might help if you include the code that triggers the action.

Comment: AS far as i can see, yes, but you'll never know :)
I added some extra code to the question

Comment: If `playHistory` has two of the same artists at the end of the array, then the condition `state.currentArtist !== action.array[0].artist` must have failed at some point even though they were the same artist -- try logging out the values to see why the if-statement is running

Comment: In theory there should be no duplicates as the station has artist seperarition. I also logged the process and if the artist changes iT has changed indeed. What do you suggest i log ?

Comment: It seems the routine is not the best. As on Android the tracks are keeping added even if the artist differs :( Tried it on ID also but also no luck. Guess it needs refactor and  my thinking point is not the right one

Comment: Anyone an idea what the best approach would be?